# Oracle unique constraint and unique index which ignoreing space

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, unique-constraint

I've used Oracle 11g and for some of the tables, used below command to create a unique index on specific column which ignores all white space.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_LOCATION_NAME ON LOCATION(UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE("FARSI_NAME",'\s+','')));
```

Recently, The Oracle database is updated to 12c and executing the mentioned command raise an error:

> [2019-06-08 19:44:08] [42000][1743] ORA-01743: only pure functions can be indexed

How can define a unique index which ignores white spaces(spaces, tab, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the reason you were allowed to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in a function based index in Oracle 11g was that it was a bug only in Oracle 11g and probably in 12.1 as well. It has been fixed since Oracle 12.2 and hence it won't allow you to create an index that uses `REGEXP_REPLACE` directly. The reason being  it's a  **Non-deterministic** function.

A similar issue exists with `CHECK` constraint too and  has been discussed in detail over [**this post**](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537768000346573035).

In your case, a simpler approach using `REPLACE` should be sufficient if you're only replacing spaces.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_LOCATION_NAME 
     ON LOCATION(UPPER(replace("FARSI_NAME",' ')));
```

The Other option to get around this problem when your replacement pattern is complex is to use an alternative function that's [**`DETERMINISTIC`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/DETERMINISTIC-clause.html#GUID-6AECC957-27CC-4334-9F43-0FBE88F92654). This is a workaround and may not be efficient for complex scenarios.

```
create or replace function my_regex_rep(txt_in VARCHAR2) 
return VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS
 BEGIN
   return regexp_replace(txt_in,'\s+','');
 END;
 /
```

Now, you are allowed to use this function in the `INDEX`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UK_LOCATION_NAME ON 
     LOCATION(UPPER(my_regex_rep("FARSI_NAME")));
```

Testing

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION(FARSI_NAME) values('ABCD EFGH');
1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO LOCATION(FARSI_NAME) values('   ABCD      efgh  ');
                                              --spaces
ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.UK_LOCATION_NAME) violated

INSERT INTO LOCATION(FARSI_NAME) values('ABCD   EFGh');
                                           --tab

ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.UK_LOCATION_NAME) violated
```

[**Oracle 18c DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f03a9e8b0b0caf6bdd35056f4a9def9)

Comment: The first solution is not good because could not check \n, \t. But the second solution works. Could describe more what you mean it may not be not efficient for a complex scenario?

Comment: @M-Razavi : What I meant was `REGEXP` are processed slowly when compared to built-ins like `replace`, `translate` etc. So, for a large table containing this index, although the selects may improve, the DMLs(updates and inserts) would considerably  slow down as the expressions to evaluate for maintaining uniqueness of rows gets complex. So, a better approach is to redesign the table structure to use an alternate `unique key` not dependant on user's input. Another option is to keep the column expressions simpler and control the inserts and updates using an application to filter out such records.